# How to check if local variable in ruby partial equals something?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

So I have a partial in my ruby app. I have a local variable "style" which is defined by some string. I want to render some h2 if this local var equals "numbered". I can't figure out the syntax...

PAGE.HTML.ERB:

```
<%= render partial: 'blocks/cards', locals: {style: "numbered", items: [
{subtitle: "", title: "Creative design", text: "<p>...</p>"},
]}%>
```

_CARDS.HTML.ERB

```
<% if ["style"] == "numbered" %>
    <h2>helloooo!</h2>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Local variables would be access via their name, e.g., `if style == "numbers"`, IIRC. You're putting the string `"style"` into an array.

Comment: Thank you, but this solution gives me "undefined local variable or method `style' for #<#<Class:0x00007fdb53f381b8>:0x00007fdb59375de8>" error unfortunately

Comment: _"I have a local variable `style`"_ – local variables have limited scope. Where do you have that variable? Can you show the code where `style` is created/assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
<% if style == "numbered" %>
```

? I'm pretty sure it's just that

Comment: Hello, Ursus! Thank you, but this solution gives me "undefined local variable or method `style' for #<#<Class:0x00007fdb53f381b8>:0x00007fdb59375de8>" error unfortunately

Comment: are you sure that that partial is not called elsewhere without the variable? because this is the way

Comment: Oh... I am really the dumbest. Thank you so much. I used it a bit earlier without this var, so got the error